# Is it necessary to wear the Silver Shroud outfit?

Tags: fallout-4

When doing the Silver Shroud quests, is it actually necessary to wear the Silver Shroud costume or can I wear my Power Armor or regular armor?

I know I can't get rid out of the outfit, but I don't see any point in wearing it.

Comment: I can't answer 100% accurately, but you for sure need the suit on both to get your targets from kent over the radio, and when meeting up with Hancock later in the mission. I'm pretty sure you can kill most targets without wearing the suit (I completed this awhile ago but I don't remember wearing it for the first couple targets myself), though the final encounter I assume you do need to be wearing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but wearing it unlocks the "Speak as Shroud" option in dialogue:

[image: With the Silver Shroud costume...]

Whereas any other armor just changes this to "Attack":

[image: ...and without it.]

Other than that, the "Speak as Shroud" option is liked by some companions. I'm not sure which, but I've personally seen it happen with Paladin Danse (which also exclaims superhero-esque phrases when you attack any of the villains).

Comment: You do need it equipped to get the targets from Kent over the radio, and when meeting up with Hancock. What about for the final encounter in the hospital?

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I'm not sure, as I already had the suit on for the special response, but I think it's wholly unnecessary for the actual kills. Kendra still referred to me as the "masked freak" even without my costume on. (I put it on mid-conversation for the dialogue)

Comment: Do you know if it works if you are wearing Power Armor on top of the Silver Shroud costume?

Comment: @PhilipPittle I'm pretty sure I tried that, and it did not work.

Comment: Power Armor negates the effects of your armor -- chameleon, speaking as Shroud, etc.